# get all playlist of an user from YouTube

Tags: android, youtube

I am working on an android application where user will login in app using their gmail account. I need to show list of youtube playlist of that user.  I have used following code -

```
 private String getAllPlayList() {
        YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            }
        }).setApplicationName("My Project").build();
        try {
            HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
            parameters.put("part", "snippet,contentDetails");
            parameters.put("mine", "true");
            parameters.put("maxResults", "25");
            parameters.put("onBehalfOfContentOwner", "");
            parameters.put("onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel", "");
            parameters.put("key","AIzaSyASISGgWoBqDijVmzUpYCbgaWJ_ULJWdiQ");

            YouTube.Playlists.List playlistsListMineRequest = youtube.playlists().list(parameters.get("part").toString());
            if (parameters.containsKey("mine") && parameters.get("mine") != "") {
                boolean mine = (parameters.get("mine") == "true") ? true : false;
                playlistsListMineRequest.setMine(true);
            }

            if (parameters.containsKey("maxResults")) {
                playlistsListMineRequest.setMaxResults(Long.parseLong(parameters.get("maxResults").toString()));
            }

            if (parameters.containsKey("onBehalfOfContentOwner") && parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwner") != "") {
                playlistsListMineRequest.setOnBehalfOfContentOwner(parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwner").toString());
            }

            if (parameters.containsKey("onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel") && parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel") != "") {
                playlistsListMineRequest.setOnBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel(parameters.get("onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel").toString());
            }
            if (parameters.containsKey("key") && parameters.get("key") != "") {
                playlistsListMineRequest.setKey(parameters.get("key").toString());
            }
            PlaylistListResponse response = playlistsListMineRequest.execute();
            Log.d("PlayList",response.toString());
            return response.toPrettyString();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage().toString();
        }

    }
```

But I am getting following response -

"message" : "The request uses the `mine` parameter but is not properly authorized.",

Please help.

Comment: Is this https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list what you're looking for?

Comment: I am unable to get result from that. response is 500

Comment: Can you post the code that you tried?

Comment: Yes. I have modified question.